Procmail. Forward mail to multiple recipients with different Message-ID
Now I have a rule in .procmailrc which performs forwarding to gmail users u1-u8
:0
* !^FROM_DAEMON
! u1[@]gmail.com,u2[@]gmail.com,u3[@]gmail.com,u4[@]gmail.com,u5[@]gmail.com,u6[@]gmail.com,u7[@]gmail.com,u8[@]gmail.com

but there was a problem, gmail refuses to immediately accept mail for these addresses with error

Gmail has detected this message exceeded its quota for sending
421-4.7.28 messages with the same Message-ID. To best protect our
users, the 421-4.7.28 message has been temporarily rejected.

Now the question. What should be the rules to forward with different Message-ID.
Can someone help?

This rule alone would send a single message. I'm guessing you have used the same input message multiple times whilst testing.

The following rule works:
:0
* !^FROM_DAEMON
{

        :0c
        | formail -I "Message-ID: <$(uuidgen)@mydomain.tld>" | sendmail -oi u1[@]gmail.com
    
        :0c
        | formail -I "Message-ID: <$(uuidgen)@mydomain.tld>" | sendmail -oi u2[@]gmail.com
    
        :0
        | formail -I "Message-ID: <$(uuidgen)@mydomain.tld>" | sendmail -oi u8[@]gmail.com
    }


This is solving the wrong problem, though. Now you're sending many separate messages instead of a single one. That's bad hygiene and inefficient.
